# Finding nullclines and linearization about the steady state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology

Here's my system:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
    \frac{du}{dt} &= u(1-u^2)-w \\[5pt] 
    \frac{dw}{dt} &= u
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

I'm coming to the conclusion that the only steady state is $(u^*,v^*)=(0,0)$, and that the nullclines are $u=0$ and $w=u(1-u^2)$. Graphing both leads to only one point of intersection, and that is at the origin. Am I wrong?

For linearization, I got the Jacobian to be, $J|_{(0,0)}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and that leads to its linearization form, $\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}\\ \dot{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Looks good. What's your question?

Comment: Just wondering if I did it correctly

Comment: Yeah, with $u=0$, you have $w=0$. Here's the vector field with nullclines superimposed. You can see the spiral source at the origin: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/drsist23bt